# Prevent ACF form from redirecting

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm using acf_form() in front end, codes (simplified) as follows,

```
//controller_and_model.php
acf_form_head();
$data = Timber::get_context();
$data['subscribe_form'] = array(
  'post_id' => 'new_post',
  'new_post' => array(
    'post_type' => 'subscription',
    'post_title' => date("Y.m.d / H:i") . ' - ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
  ),
  'submit_value' => __("SUBSCRIBE", 'my_theme'),
  'updated_message' => 'Thank you for subscribe!',
  'return' => false
);
Timber::render('view.twig', $data);
```

```
//view.twig
{{ fn('acf_form', subscribe_form) }}
```

Everything works fine except `'return' => false` doesn't prevent redirection, have tried `'return' => ''` and without the `'return'` line, but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if there are similar questions with working solution, please kindly post as a comment.

Comment: ACF doesn't [appear to](https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/blob/c8e181c848009aa9f6a3919ee19981fb2774f634/includes/forms/form-front.php#L443) do a redirect at all if `return` is empty. This could be default WP behavior, in which case it is by design. You typically want to do a redirect after a successful POST anyway, to prevent accidental duplicate submissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up using a custom form with an wp ajax action to insert the post.